# harmony proxies in v8

Tags: javascript, v8

I'm having a problem emulating noSuchMethod in v8. I'm activating harmony proxies correctly at command line (I don't get errors using the Proxy() object and I'm able to use *some* proxy features) yet none of the examples that I've found have worked for noSuchMethod.

```
var NoSuchMethodTrap = Proxy.create({
  // FIXME: don't know why I need to provide this method,
  // JS complains if getPropertyDescriptor is left out, or returns undefined
  // Apparently, this method is called twice: once for '_noSuchMethod_' and once for 'foo'
  getPropertyDescriptor: function(n){ return {} }, 
  get: function(rcvr, name) {
    if (name === '__noSuchMethod__') {
      throw new Error("receiver does not implement __noSuchMethod__ hook");
    } else {
      return function() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        return this.__noSuchMethod__(name, args);
      }
    }
  }
});

function MyObject() {};
MyObject.prototype = Object.create(NoSuchMethodTrap);
MyObject.prototype.__noSuchMethod__ = function(methName, args) {
  return 'Hello, '+methName;
};
```

I included the code snipplit of what I'm trying but it's a bit worthless since it's the same case no matter where I get the code. I've been google'ing this for a week now.  So here's the question: Is this simply not implemented in v8? What am I missing if so?

Answer (score 0):

Just to close the loop here: the Proxy spec has changed quite a bit, and V8 by now implements the full new spec. No flags are necessary any more, and there should be no missing features.